# MySQL update trigger - how to detect unpassed values?

Tags: mysql, triggers

Let's say I have these possible queries:

```
UPDATE table SET field1 = 2 WHERE id = 1;
UPDATE table SET field1 = 4, field2 = 8 WHERE id = 16;
```

`table` has a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger that calculates a new value for `field2` based on `field1`, but I want it to only do this if I don't specifically pass a value.

I am detecting a change to `field1` with `IF OLD.field1 != NEW.field1 THEN ...`, but how do I detect `field2` being passed or not, regardless of the value actually changing?

Answer (score 1):

If MySQL does not receive a value through the UPDATE for `field2` it will contain the old value in `NEW.field2`.

In Oracle you will get a NULL if the `field2` is not passed trough the update.

If `NEW` and `OLD` values are the same you can assume that no update is required for that field. MySQL will also return 0 rows updated if all `NEW` values match what is already there in the table.